# xgboost algorithm implementation in R- what's the meaning of labels in the code?

Tags: r

I'm trying to implement xgboost algo & this is the code that I'm using :

```
  set.seed(100)
  setwd("C:\\Users\\ts93856\\Desktop\\datasource")
  # load data
  df_train = read_csv("train_users_2.csv")
  df_test = read_csv("test_users.csv")
  # Loading labels of train data
  labels = df_train['labels']
  df_train = df_train[-grep('labels', colnames(df_train))]
```

I'm unable to understand what is labels here.Please refer to the code from this link https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/01/xgboost-algorithm-easy-steps/ & help me understanding labels and label parameter of xgboost() function.

Answer (score 0):

The 'labels' are the outcome values. They are passed separately to XGBoost as `label` so they need to be split off from the data frame first. The `data` argument then contains only the predictive features, not the outcomes.